# How to implement the expected output using Jolttransfromjson In Apache Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Please help me out in achieving the expected output in Jolt.

**Input** :

```json
{
  "kind": "bresponse",
  "schema": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "export_time",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "account_id",
        "type": "STRING",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      },
      {
        "name": "cost",
        "type": "FLOAT",
        "mode": "NULLABLE"
      }
    ]
  },
  "jobReference": {
    "projectId": "avach",
    "jobId": "job_G4hQs",
    "location": "ui"
  },
  "totalRows": "49",
  "pageToken": "BG123",
  "rows": [
    {
      "f": [
        {
          "v": "20230"
        },
        {
          "v": "0107F6-7"
        },
        {
          "v": "0.0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "f": [
        {
          "v": "20230101"
        },
        {
          "v": "01DC85-B"
        },
        {
          "v": "3.48E-4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "totalBytesProcessed": "37472",
  "jobComplete": true,
  "cacheHit": false
}
```

**Expected output** :

```json
[
  {
    "export_time": "20230",
    "account_id": "0107F6-7",
    "cost": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "export_time": "20230101",
    "account_id": "01DC85-B",
    "cost": "3.48E-4"
  }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Is my question is clear or do i need to explain anything @BARBAROS OZHAN

Comment: U r the one who will provide solutions for complexity jolt transforms in my opinion so i am asking u pls help me out.

Comment: Sure Ofcourse Barbaros Ozhan

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **shift** transformation spec in which

- go 5 levels up (traverse once`:`, and `{` four times ) in order to reach
  fields array as picking sub-arrays of data array by using `[&1]`
- dissipate all returning key-value pairs through use of `[&3].` node

such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "rows": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "@v": "[&3].@(5,schema.fields[&].name)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Have a nice study @Sathish

Comment: Could u pls help with the documentation on jolt, So that i can explore more on this jolt specifications

Comment: @Sathish There are some links and blogs which I like and recommend such as [1](https://cool-cheng.blogspot.com/2019/12/json-jolt-tutorial.html), [2](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases), [3](https://erbalvindersingh.medium.com/applying-jolttransform-on-json-object-array-and-fetching-specific-fields-48946870b4fc), [4](https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/3096940-simple-if-else-with-jolt), [5](https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/3159219-transformer-operations-overview) Have a nice study!